# HTML - element over <video> element (also in full screen mode)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-video

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that add 
video control features to a specific site that display videos.
So far I managed to add 'keydown' eventListeners that allow me to seek forward&backward and change playback speed.

I want to add some visual feedback to the playback speed change. Best example is YouTube videos.
If SHIFT+'>' or SHIFT+'<' is pressed there is a fading div over the video that indicates the speed change.
**It works also in full screen mode**.

I have tried 'appendChild' to the `<video>` element but nothing seems to happen, not even an error.

```
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.backgroundColor ='red';
    div.style.zIndex = '10'
    div.style.width = '300px';
    div.style.height = '300px';

    document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].appendChild(div)
```

Any idea how to achieve YouTube-like behavior?

Comment: Create a div and set its position to relative, then group the video in that div with the 'wrap' method and then you play the new div in it with position absolute

Comment: Can you please give a code example? 
There are several things I don't understand:
1) Is 'warp' a jQuery method?
2) What do you mean by 'play the new div in it'

Comment: `<video>` can't have visible children so you can't append there. Append afterwards and use getBoundingClientRect on the original video to set CSS position on the new div.

Comment: Eventually I'v used insertBefore() on  the parent node of <video>.
Combined with flexbox , it works like a charm.
Thanks!